# Package installed with venv not found in Django settings

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I started my `django` project with `venv`. I created a `venv` and installed django there. Now I needed another package `django-ckeditor` and I installed it with `pip` inside my venv this way.
`(env) X@Z:~/work/mod/website$ pip install django-ckeditor`

And it was installed successfully.

**Edit**

I went to my `python-shell` from `Pycharm` and typed

`import ckeditor` 
It did not work first and it showed

> no module found

Then I did this:

`import sys`

`sys.path.append("X/mod/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages")`

And then
`import ckeditor` 
and it worked!

there's no error. But when I try to include it in the django `settings.py` 
django does not find it.

I included it in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section and the library name I included is `ckeditor`.

My project structure is

```
venv
mysite
|--mysite
   |--settings.py
```

How to resolve this issue?

**Edit2**
I don't know what happened but I closed and restarted `Pycharm` and it worked!

Comment: How exactly do you start Django?

Comment: From my `mysite` directory, `source ../venv/bin/activate`, then `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: have you gon through https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#installation ?

Comment: See the question, I've mentioned that I've installed it in my `venv`

Comment: I've edited in my question. Feel free to ask me more if you have any confusion.

Comment: If you use pycharm and you want to use your package installed in your venv you must add it in your pycharm settings.

Comment: @NathanIngram I did that too

Comment: If you have done that try to list all your package installed in your pycharm settings...

Comment: pycharm can list you all project package and all versus !

Comment: @NathanIngram yeah I know, and yes I can see my package there too. It's just when I am trying to include the lib in the `INSTALLED_APPS` it's not working

Comment: ok.. I don't what actually happened, but I just closed the pycharm and re started it and it worked! Weird!!!

Comment: If your installed package listed with pycharm, i dont see reason why pycharm cannot import it correctly. Try to find your search app and it versus...

Comment: I hope that my comment help you ! I saw it in pycharm app, i hope that's not plagearism...

Comment: I don't understand why would it be plagiarism?

Answer (score 1):

List all your projects apps already installed in your pycharm settings and it versus, try to find your app, if it not listed install it with pip like:

```
pip install myapp
```

Restard your pycharm, it may work...

***I hope it's not cheating, pycharm is so well built that it solves problems by itself.***

Comment: It's not cheating but I am confused too... Pycharm is damn intelligent and I never encountered a problem, related to Pycharm before... What I think is I was making comment with you from my phone because my pc got hung up as it doesn't have much ram and I think probably that's why it couldn't indexing the new packages! Who knows!

Comment: I am glad to have helped you ... I hope I have not plagiarized on pycharm :)